# How to call a superclass method within an advice?

Tags: java, inheritance, aspectj, super

I'm working on a project which aims to introduce modifications in a code base without directly change the source code, these changes have already been implemented and I am rewriting the code with AspectJ

So far I managed to implement all changes using AspectJ. But I don't know how to implement it:

- There is a method called `beforeCadastrarAndValidate ()` which was overridden by a subclass. At the end of this method was inserted the following line: `super.beforeCadastrarAndValidate ()`
- This line of code call the method from superclass. I can capture the execution of this method, but I have no idea how to call the method of the superclass. I already searched and I know that it's not possibel to call "super" in a advice. I tried using Reflection too, but I have not found a solution.

There is a way I can do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could call it from the superclass using reflection.

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

class Person {
  public void greet() {
    System.out.println("Person's greet");
  }
}

class Employee extends Person {
  public void greet() {
    System.out.println("Employee's greet");
  }
}

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) 
        throws Exception {
    // get the method object from Person class.
    Method g = Person.class.getMethod("greet",
                     new Class[0]);

    Employee e = new Employee();
    // When "g" is invoked on an "Employee" object, 
    // the "Employee.greet" method is called.
    g.invoke(e, null);
  }
}
```

**Reference: https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/calling_overriden_superclass_method_on**

Comment: Thanks Experminator.

But in this way you are creating a new instance of the object "Person". I have to call a method from a managed bean and I can't create a new instance. This is why I think Reflection isn't an option. At least no in this way you suggest.